# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application whenever I call any controller action or page reload my terminal shows some errors there but my application works quite normal, no functionality got stuck, but I don't know why this happens, as I have noticed it now. Is there any way to solve it.

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-04 15:49:29 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"):
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  request_store (1.2.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (9.9ms)
  Rendered /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered /home/praveen/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (96.6ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-04 15:49:29 +0530
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for `@font-face` in your css files and set the path to your assets accordingly.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 src: url("<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.eot' %>");
 src: url("<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix' %>") format('embedded-opentype'), url("<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.woff' %>") format('woff'), url("<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.ttf' %>") format('truetype'), url("<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular' %>") format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: sorry that doesnt solved the problem still the same errors are displayed.